# Pyscript taking forever to load after importing

Tags: python, html, pyscript

So, I'm using PyScript for my website. Using Live Server, my website is taking forever to load after I try to install sklearn. My PyScript code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<py-env>
      - numpy
      - pandas
      - sklearn.model_selection
      - sklearn.naive_bayes
      - sklearn.feature_extraction
</py-env>
<py-script>
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd
      from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
      from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, and note that this only happens when I install skearn, it just says this for (at what seems to be the case at this rate) forever:

> Loading runtime...
> Runtime created...
> Initializing components...

What can I do about this? It is very frustrating.

Comment: Open the Chrome debugger. Go to the Network tab. Refresh the page. You can see what is being downloaded, what is being cached, etc. Also, review the Console tab. Edit your question with details.

Answer (score 0):

I think pyscript will install package in  tag when every time reload page and it only support package suuport in [Packages built in Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html).

Otherwise because it is install by nicropip from PyPl , you should replace it with "scikit-learn".

I think it might work:)

```
<py-env>
      - numpy
      - pandas
      - scikit-learn
</py-env>
<py-script>
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd
      from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
      from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
</py-script>
```

Comment: The way you wrote your answer is confusing. A page refresh reloads PyScript and Pyodide. However, depending on how the package vendor configures caching, downloads from the network might not be required. You can also configure a PyScript application to be a PWA which means the Internet is not even required. https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-creating-installable-offline-applications/

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh I get it. I alway use Ctrl+F5 to refrsh my page without cache so it need to reinstall every time. Thanks a lot for this comment and I learn very much from your article.